# PhpStorm: how to setting up to substitute old name with new one when you choose other variable from dropdown

Tags: phpstorm

There is option in ZDE when you select needed variable from the help dropdown it substitutes old name with new one. But PhpStorm just adds content, doesn't replace it.

Ex. say I have variable `$var1`. I need replace it with `$some_existing_var`. I start to type, PhpStorm shows me help, I press enter and get `$some_existing_varvar1`.

Where is settings for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete an entry from code completion popup instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

- <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts entry as is
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> inserts & replaces current entry

[Official help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/using-suggestion-list.html?search=complet#d820782e138).